# Traducción de "nonce words" en español

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, lingüística

Necesito hacer la traducción de un artículo de investigación en lingüística y me encontré con el término "nonce words", que hace referencia a un lexema no existente en la lengua objeto de estudio, creado *ad hoc*. Estuve buscando artículos en español para ver si encontraba alguno en el que se empleara la forma española de este término, pero no encontré ninguno (tampoco dispongo de mucho tiempo como para hacer una búsqueda extensa).

¿Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: No son sinónimos exactos, pero hay [palabro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RUwWhqA) y [hápax](https://dle.rae.es/?id=K0iLfgK). Además hay la frase "palabra [*ad hoc*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0jmLlgY)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En inglés un sinónimo de *nonce word* es ***occasionalism***; esta salida también se adopta en italiano (*occasionalismo*). El único problema es que *[ocasionalismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocasionalismo)* es también el nombre de una doctrina o conjunto de teorías filosóficas (que no tienen nada que ver con la creación de palabras *ad hoc*).

De todas formas, esto no es un problema: no sería la primera vez que un término técnico se refiriese a dos cosas totalmente diferentes, y el contexto siempre permitirá diferenciarlos.

Los términos ***palabra ocasional*** y ***ocasionalismo*** aparecen en un artículo [sobre un poema de Juan Gelman](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0185308213724106) (en el texto y en una de las notas, respectivamente) refiriéndose explícitamente a *nonce words*.

[image: ocasionalismo]

En otro artículo (de la Revista Nebrija, sobre "[Calcos y otras estrategias compensatorias en dos tipos de enseñanza bilingüe finés-español](https://www.nebrija.com/revista-linguistica/files/articulosPDF/articulo_582cb2759f6d5.pdf)" [PDF]) se habla de *préstamos ocasionales* y una nota aclara que esta expresión es traducción de *nonce borrowing*.

Hay unos cuantos ejemplos más que no citaré porque se pueden encontrar fácilmente combinando los términos *nonce word palabra ocasional* y similares.

Por lo dicho yo sugeriría que la traducción castellana de *nonce word* debería ser *palabra ocasional* u *ocasionalismo*, tomando la precaución de definirla, por supuesto, inmediatamente después del primer uso, para evitar confusiones.

Comment: ¡Listo! Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás [**hápax**](https://dle.rae.es/h%C3%A1pax):

> Del gr. ἅπαξ [λεγόμενον] *hápax [legómenon]* '[dicho] una sola vez'.
>
> 1. m. Ling. En lexicografía o en crítica textual, voz registrada una sola vez en una lengua, en un autor o en un texto.

Como despues de escribir la respuesta he visto que ya ha sido indicada en un comentario a la pregunta original por [brazofuerte](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/18348/brazofuerte), yo borraría esta respuesta, pero el sistema no me deja, pese a lo que se indica en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers:

> Answers can be deleted at any time by their authors, unless the answer has been accepted by the question asker.

Comment: Eso no importa, alguien tenía que responder y ésta merece ser la respuesta aceptada. *Ocasionalismo* no me parece una palabra idiomática y además es demasiado larga, torpe y una traducción muy poco original. Me quedo con esta palabra